# for x in lst - does x is the pointer or the value itself

Tags: python, list, for-loop, memory-management

I have tried to run this code:

```
a = 1000
d = [a,2]
d[1] = -1
a = 1003
for x in d: 
    x = 7
```

I wonder why don't all the list elements values change to 7?

Like when I run

```
d[1] = -1
```

This statement has changed the value of the second element in the list from 1,000 to -1.

The way I understand it, its this -
In every iteration of the for-loop, x equals to some pointer in the list. for example in the first iteration we actually make the next statement -

```
d[0] = 7
```

And then the first element supposed to be changed from 1,000 to 7.

Where do I get wrong?

This a Pyhton-Tutor screenshot that can help:
[Pyhton-TutorSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uITut.png)

Comment: `x` is a value in `lst`. It is not a pointer to a position in `lst`. Python does not work like that.

Comment: I`m not trying to make it. I`m trying to understand the memory issue behind this code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem and Python itself, `x` is neither pointer not element - it is an image (copy) of an element of `d`. I am far from being an expert, but I believe this is intended for optimisation purposes and using pure python you can not change simple objects in this way.

I am not sure if this behaviour will be same for large, complex objects - unfortunately in python some objects are "soft copied", while other are "hard copied" in these cases. Here, `x` is a hard copy of `d[1]`, meaning these two objects are not related anymore (see `a` in your example).

If you want to change a list in this manner, you can use the following snippet:

```
for i, x in enumerate(d):
    d[i] = 7
```

`enumerate` is a built-in function which assigns an index to every element. In this way you can iterate though `d`, and for each element of `d` get its image `x` and its "pointer" (index) `i`, which you can use to assign to the original list.

Please mind redefining the list you iterate through might be ill-advised. This kind of operation should be most likely done by declaring a new list, for example using a list comprehension:

```
d = [7 for x in d]
```

This will generate a new list `d`, where for every image `x` in original `d` it will assign a value of `7`.